# Datetime get time of the next day at exactly 9 AM by the selected time zone

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, datetimeoffset

I have a code like this:

```
var info = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central European Standard Time");
var localServerTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;
DateTimeOffset localTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(localServerTime, info);
```

This gets me a desired "CEST" current time regardless of the server location. Now I would like to extract from this variable date that is set in future.

For example, today is 2nd of July 2018 11:24 AM by my local time. The "setInFuture" DateTime should be set to 3rd of July 2018 9:10 AM

Another example:

14th of July 2018 11:24 AM by my local time. The "setInFuture" DateTime should be set to 15th of July 2018 9:10 AM

So the set in future variable should always be next day of CEST current time at 9:10 AM...

How can I achieve this, regardless of what current time it is at CEST?

Can someone help me out?

Comment: `var setInFuture = cestDateTimeNow.Date.AddHours(24 + 9)`

Comment: "Exactly 9 AM" and 9:10 AM is different for me.

Comment: `var tomorrowAt0910 = localTime.AddDays(1).Date + new TimeSpan(9, 10, 0);`

Comment: @MatthewWatson what happens if this is called the day before summer time ends for the target timezone? The offset won't change, resulting in the wrong time.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No, it will still be the correct local time. The following code prints `28/10/2018 09:10:00`: `var localTime = new DateTime(2018, 10, 27, 20, 30, 40); var tomorrowAt0910 = localTime.AddDays(1).Date + new TimeSpan(9, 10, 0); Console.WriteLine(tomorrowAt0910);`

Comment: If you were to print `Console.WriteLine(tomorrowAt0910.ToUniversalTime() - localTime.ToUniversalTime());` then if the date is `26` or `28` in the sample code above you get `12:39:20` output, but if the date is `27` you get `13:39:20`.